# Como eu faço para guardar um valor obtido do sequelize numa variável em node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Utilizo o seguinte código

```
var app = website.findOne({ where: { idwebsite: req.params.id } })
res.send(app);
```

Porém o resultado na tela e esse {"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}
Como eu faço para guardar o real valor do select na variável app?

Answer (score 1):

Ola,

Pelo erro apresentado você deve estar recebendo uma promise como retorno, existem dois modos de ligar com situações assincronas no javascript

Usando async/await

```
async getData() {
  return await website.findOne({ where: { idwebsite: req.params.id } })
} 
const app = await getData();
res.send(app);
```

salvo engano assim já funcionaria:

```
getData() {
  return website.findOne({ where: { idwebsite: req.params.id } })
} 
const app = await getData();
res.send(app);
```

ou lidando com as promises por then/catch

```
let app;
website.findOne({ where: { idwebsite: req.params.id } }).
then( data => {
  app = data;
  res.send(app);
})
```

ps. esses códigos não foram testados